# Displaying one Django database object on a page at a time

Tags: python, django

I'm in the early stages of a project and want to know if this is possible:

I have 10 objects in my database that represent a person (id, name, age, sex, location). What I'd like to do is display each person on their own page with a custom url (example.com/person/1, example.com/person/2, etc.).

My model and view below work for showing everyone at the same time on one page. How can I rewrite this to show one person on a page at a time?

Here's my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%r, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s" % (self.id, self.name, self.age, self.sex, self.location)
```

Here's my view:

```
def person(request):
    person_info = Person.objects.all()
    person_data = {
        "person_detail" : person_info
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', person_data)
```

I'm new to Django and apologize if I'm missing an obvious answer.

Comment: This is exactly the situation discussed in the tutorial, with the Question class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `views.py` file must take an argument when you are trying to display a specific profile.

try this:

```
def person(request, id):
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'person/index.html', {'person': person, })
```

This should do.

Also, you must add an entry in the urls.py file,

```
url(r'/person/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.person),
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.

All you have to do is: modify your urls.py to define URL with parameter, extract that parameter in view (it will be passed to view as argument or keyword argument) and extract one person, using get or filter instead of all.

Answer (score 0):

**Just an example**

You need to create one more function with name example "profile_data"

views.py

```
def profile_data(request,userid)
    person_info = Person.objects.get(id=userid)
    person_data = {
    "person_detail" : person_info
     }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', person_data)
```

url.py

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<userid>\d+)/$', app.views.profile)
```

You need to pass the userid to that url,in this way you get that details of that particular user.

Comment: You should use `get` instead of `filter`, `filter` returns a list, where as `get` returns only the object asked.